# How can I mass edit mysql tables in one field ONLY WHEN another field meets exact requirements?

Tags: mysql, phpbb3

A situation looks like that:
I want to make a **mass edit** in MySQL database for phpBB 3. I have already seen MySQL queries here that told me how can I do such a mass edit for (for example) post_text and change all the links.

I know I can do it that way:

> UPDATE phpbb_posts SET post_text='new_link.eu' WHERE post_text IS
>   'old_link.eu'.

And I know that will change all of the links to old_link.eu to new_link.eu.

But my situation is different. I want to **make that edit only to the posts that meet exact requirements.** There are very simple - I want the query to change only **posts that have specific forum_id field** (they belong to the proper subforum, where I want to see the change).

I believe it is a thing that could be helpful to many people using different scripts.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's some complexity to your requirement we can't see from here, you should be able to do this very easily.

```
  UPDATE phpbb_posts 
     SET post_text='new_link.eu' 
   WHERE post_text = 'old_link.eu'
     AND forum_id = <<whatever>>
```

You should definitely back up your table contents before you do this.  If you fat-finger something in the query, it will be very hard to recover unless you have a backup.

You might also try

```
  SELECT *
    FROM phpbb_posts 
   WHERE post_text = 'old_link.eu'
     AND forum_id = <<whatever>>
```

before you run your update to make sure you're getting the right rows.

Comment: Big thanks, but - I don't know why - it doesn't seem to be working, though I write down the query exactly the way You put it here.

It looks exactly like this (the words below are Polish, so don't mind)
UPDATE phpbb_posts 
     SET post_text='Uczeń Jedi' 
   WHERE post_text = 'Jedi Apprentice'
     AND forum_id = 123

Of course, I want to change word "Jedi Apprentice" to "Uczeń Jedi" in every post from phpbb3 that belongs to the subforum which's ID is 123. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you get when you do this query? `SELECT * from phpbb_posts  WHERE post_text = 'Jedi Apprentice' AND forum_id = 123`  You should get the records you're hoping to update.